# started learning :Button

Tags: android, button

I am using this code and still I am at a very early stage but I am learning from thenewboston videos and seems few things in coding has changed since he published his tutorials

i am entering this code

```
 <button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Love"
    android:textSize="50sp" />
```

but it is not making Love word inside the button, the word keeps button not changing
Tell me what is wrong

Comment: If you are learning, you should understand that XML is not code.  It's data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `button`, it's `Button`. The XML tag points to the java class in the framework. And Java is case sensitive.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Love"
    android:textSize="50sp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Change 'button' to 'Button',Its case sensitive

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Love"
    android:textSize="50sp" />
```